# Replace Numerical Reference of a formula VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

```
For i = 1 To 5
    changeto = CStr(Sheet15.Cells(1, i).Formula)
    newindustry = getfirstword(Worksheets("Industry Insert Template").Range("C1"))
    'grab the index position of the comma and exclamation mark
    intchangeto = InStr(changeto, ",")
    finalchangeto = InStr(changeto, "!")
    'extract the worksheet substring
    finalindustry = Mid(changeto, intchangeto + 1, finalchangeto - intchangeto - 1)

    If finalindustry <> "'Multiples & EPS'" And finalindustry <> "Technicals" Then
        finalformula = Replace(changeto, finalindustry, newindustry)
        Cells(1, i).Formula = finalformula
    End If
Next
```

Currently this is my macro to adjust the worksheet name.
I want to adjust only the numerical reference.

For example:

```
=VLOOKUP($B1,Industrials!$CA$41:$GG$41,C$8)
```

I want to be able to change the cells 41 in the vlookup to reflect the correct row. 
How would I go through all the cells and change the formula to reflect this?

Comment: Better of to use named ranges. That is what they are there for.

Comment: You could take a look at using R1C1 style addressing: accessed in VBA with `.FormulaR1C1`

Answer (score 0):

Use *Replace*:

Example :

```
Cells (1, i).Formula = Replace(Cells (1, i).Formula, oldRow, NewRow)
```

If the value of `i` is related to the row number, you can use it in place of old row etc.